# Array Tester - Beginner

Tags: java, arrays

I am long time lurker and first time user of overflow, hopefully someone will be able to help guide me in the right direction. There are clearly more issues with the program than I'd like to admit, however, I'm getting there! My main concerns at the moment are below...

1. My first question is about looping my program back to the beginning. For example, if the user inputs an integer < 1 the program outputs an ERROR MESSAGE. The program stops there. How can I loop it back to prompt the user to input another integer.
2. I am also having an issue when the program prompts the user to "Enter a list of () integers:" For some reason, I have to enter more integers than I should have to. In the end, the program only takes the appropriate number, which is pretty weird. (SEE the PROGRAM TEST - Notice 1 through 5 then integer 6 below that. I hit enter after 5 but the program doesn't continue. It only continues when I hit enter, type 6 and then hit enter again. The array below that is accurate though.)
3. Let me know if I should change anything else.

Hopefully I will be able to post my updated code when I get this figured out! Thanks in advance if you have read to this point!
     /**
     * N Irwin - Programming I - Lab 23
     * Array Tester - 4/21/2016
     */

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayTest
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   { 

     /**
      * Beginning of Program and OUTPUT.
      */
     System.out.println("       * * * Array Test * * *");
     System.out.println("      WRITTEN by N Irwin");
     System.out.println();

     /**
      * Scanner object.
      */
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     /**
      * Program OUTPUT - user is required to provide input.
      */
     System.out.print("Enter the number of integers to read: ");
     int integerNumber = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println();

     /**
      * Program begins if integer is greater than or equal to 1.
      */
     if(integerNumber >= 1)
     {

     /**
      * Program OUTPUT - user is required to provide input.
      */
     final int LENGTH = 100;
     int[] values = new int [LENGTH];
     int currentSize = 0;

     System.out.print("Enter a list of " + integerNumber + " integers: ");

     /**
      * 
      */
     while (input.hasNextInt() && currentSize < integerNumber)
     {
         if (currentSize < values.length)
         {
             values[currentSize] = input.nextInt();
             currentSize++;
            }
        }

     /**
      * Program OUTPUT - integers in listed formatting.
      */
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Your integers are:");
     System.out.println();

     int listNumber = 1;

     for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
     {
         System.out.printf("%6d", listNumber);
         System.out.println(". " + values[i]);
         listNumber++;
        }

     /**
      * Program OUTPUT - integers in listed formatting in reverse.
      */
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Your integers in reverse are:");
     System.out.println();

     int listReverse = 1;

     for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
     {
         System.out.printf("%6d", listReverse);
         System.out.println(". " + values[i]);
         listReverse++;
        }

     /**
      * Program OUTPUT - total of integers.
      */

     double totalInteger = 0;

     for (int element : values)
     {
         totalInteger += element;
        }

     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("The total of these " + integerNumber + " numbers is: " + totalInteger);
     System.out.println();

     /**
      * Program OUTPUT - average of integers.
      */

     double averageInteger = 0;

     if (values.length > 0)
     {
         averageInteger = (totalInteger / integerNumber);
        }

     System.out.print("The average of these " + integerNumber + " numbers is: ");
     System.out.printf("%.1f", averageInteger);
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println();

     /**
      * Program OUTPUT - minimum integer.
      */

     int minimumInteger = values[0];

     for(int i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
     {
         if (values[i] < minimumInteger)
         {
             minimumInteger = values[i];
            }
        }

     System.out.println("The minimum value in these " + integerNumber + " numbers is: " + minimumInteger);
     System.out.println();

     /**
      * Program OUTPUT - maximum integer.
      */

     int maximumInteger = values[0];

     for(int i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
     {
         if (values[i] > maximumInteger)
         {
             maximumInteger = values[i];
            }
        }

     System.out.println("The maximum value in these " + integerNumber + " numbers is: " + maximumInteger);
     System.out.println();

     /**
      * Program OUTPUT - pairs that have been summed.
      */
     System.out.println("Summing pairs of numbers produces: ");
     System.out.println();
    }

    /**
      * Program produces an ERROR message if the integer is less than 1.
      */
    else
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: The integer you entered was invalid.");
    }
}
}
```

---

```
***** PROGRAM TEST *****

* * * Array Test * * *
WRITTEN by Nathan Irwin

Enter the number of integers to read: 5
```

Enter a list of 5 integers: 1 2 3 4 5
6

Your integers are:

```
 1. 1
 2. 2
 3. 3
 4. 4
 5. 5
```

Your integers in reverse are:

```
 1. 1
 2. 2
 3. 3
 4. 4
 5. 5
```

The total of these 5 numbers is: 15.0

The average of these 5 numbers is: 3.0

The minimum value in these 5 numbers is: 0

The maximum value in these 5 numbers is: 5

Summing pairs of numbers produces:

Comment: Debugger might help you out

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the user mandatorily enters a `number > 1` you can do it like this:

```
int integerNumber;

do{
  integerNumber = input.nextInt();

  if(integerNumber < 1)
     System.out.println("Error");
}while(integerNumber < 1);
```

so the input will be always display until the user enters a `number > 1`.

For your second question, you can read the full line of numbers and then [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) (divide) the string that you have read taking as reference the space that you put between each number. Like this:

```
String string = input.nextLine(); //Reads the full line
String[] parts = string.split(" "); //Here you divide the string directly in an array taking as reference the space between each number

for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
{
   System.out.println(parts[i]); //You will see each input that you have done
}
```

I expect it will be helpful for you. Do not doubt to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to help me. I was able to implement the first part in beautifully. The second part, however, I don't think will work for me. I understand how you did it but when it comes time for me to total up the integers, how would I be able to turn those values into integers? Eventually I will have to sum up my first array with another array, also, I think.....

Comment: @N.Irwin If you want to convert a `String` to an `int` you can use `int number = Integer.parseInt(string);`

Comment: @N.Irwin By the moment I suppose that you are going to enter all the values correctly (as numbers) because if you try to convert a letter it may give to you an error.